# Running an application in different versions of iPad

Tags: ipad, xcode4.3

I am working with iOS native application with objective C as front end and SUP 2.1.3 as backend.I am using xcode 4.3.2.I have set my deployment target as 5.0. The app is workin fine on iPad 5.0 and iPad 5.1.Can I run the same application in iPad 6.1.3?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the application ..It is working fine.From this I got the information that,I have to set the minimum version in which we have to deploy the application .So If our deployment target is 5.0 it will run on any higher version